# avoid suspending app in titanium appcelerator

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I am doing a GPS, and the minute the screen is locked, I would not bloquera, be difficult to do?

Since the application is finished , i guess I should modify the file tiapp.xml , several applications but do not find examples of how to do it

Thank You

Comment: Explain your problem more fully and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to understand but if i'm right you are looking for a way to block the mobile to sleep.

If you are in Alloy mode you can add "keepScreenOn: true" to the properties :

".container" : {
    keepScreenOn: true
}

Next time try to give more details about your question.